# JQuery .on 'change' event doesn't get fired for a dropdown inside a partial view

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I'm trying to mask a text field for phone numbers on change of the dropdownlist. Both the text field and the dropdownlist are present inside a partial view which is dynamically loaded. However, the on.change event doesn't get fired at all. Please help!

**jQuery**

```js
$.ajax({
  url: '/Brd/CreatePointofContact'
}).success(function (partialView) {
  $('#newPocs').append(partialView);
}); //this is what loads the partial view

//doesn't work 
$(document).on("change", "#NumberTypeId", function () {
  alert("Hi!");
  //do masking here
});

//this doesn't work either
$("#NumberTypeId").on('change', function (e) {
  alert("Hi!");
  var mask = "(999)-999-9999";
  var valueSelected = this.value;
  if (valueSelected == 1) {
    $('#PhoneNumber').mask(mask);
  } else {
    $('#PhoneNumber').unmask(mask);
  }
});
```

**Main view**

```html
<div id="newPocs">
  @for (int i = 0; i < @Model.NewPocs.Count(); i++)
  {
    @Html.EditorFor(model => @Model.NewPocs[i])
  }
</div>
```

**Partial View** (dynamically loaded)

```
<div class="col-md-3">
  @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.NumberTypeId, @Model.NumberType, "-- Select --", new { @class = "form-control" })
</div>
<div class="col-md-2">
  @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.PhoneNumber, new { @placeholder = "Phone Number", @class = "form-control" })
</div>
```

Comment: Please only use the actual HTML output when creating a code snippet.

Comment: I thought it would be beneficial to let people know how I load my partial view to be able to help better!

Comment: That is to say, the code snippet does not recognize Razor markup. But your Razor code is still useful to share to demonstrate your problem.

Comment: Is the jquery on the partial view?  And if so is it in a Code Block?  If so you cant use code blocks on partial views.  Also make sure your jquery library is loaded before the partial.

Comment: If you are loading your partial in a loop check the rendered html to be sure you don't have duplicate `id` attributes.

Comment: `$(document).on("change", "#NumberTypeId", function () {..` will work, but the script needs to be on the main page. I assume you must have it in the partial. If thats not working, look at the html generated by your `@Html.EditorFor()` method (is the `id` "NumberTypeId" or "NumberTypeId[0]")

Comment: i put this script in the main page

Comment: Then check the html. You not using `EditorFor()` correctly anyway (you should not have a loop - its just `@Html.EditorFor(m => m.NewPocs)`. In the partial, give the elements a class name and use that rather than an id. `$(document).on('change', ".number", function () { ..`

Answer (score 4):

If you're loading that Partial View asynchronously, then the element doesn't exist when your JavaScript gets parsed. You're doing the right thing by setting up a delegate, however it won't work when looking at the `$(document)` object. Wrap your Partial View loading inside of a `<div>` that will always be there.

If you were to put it inside your "newPocs" div, your JavaScript should look like this:

```
$('#newPocs').on("change", "#NumberTypeId", function () {
    alert("Hi!");
    //do masking here
});
```

That should work for you, regardless of how many times you reload your Partial View without reloading the entire page.

Comment: tried this but didn't work. also, the newPocs div exists in the page, but the NumberTypeId element doesn't

Comment: Is your `#NumberTypeId` element a child of `#newPocs`? You do only have one `#NumberTypeId` element?

Comment: You are checking the source HTML in your browser to ensure that the IDs are correct?

Comment: yes, so the #NumberTypeId is in the partial view which i'm appending to #newPocs div in the main page like  - 
`$.ajax({
                url: '/Brd/CreatePointofContact'
            }).success(function (partialView) {
                $('#newPocs').append(partialView);
            });`

Answer (score 1):

when partial view loaded from jquery ajax in success include:

```
success: function (result) {
         $('.classSelect').on('change', SelectChangeExample);
}
```

then create a function:

```
   function SelectChangeExample() {
         alert('test');
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it to work by just giving @id explicitly to the dropdownlist in my partial view.
My bad for not figuring this out early!

```js
**the jQuery remained the same**
  
  $(document).on('change', '#NumberTypeId', function () {
            alert("Hi!");
        });
```

```html
**instead of**

<div class="col-md-3">
  @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.NumberTypeId, @Model.NumberType, "-- Select --", new { @class = "form-control" })
</div>

**declared @id property as follows**

<div class="col-md-3">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.NumberTypeId, @Model.NumberType, "-- Select --", new { @id = "NumberTypeId", @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
```

Comment: `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.NumberTypeId, ....)` does generate `id=NumberTypeId"` in the html so your solution does absolutely nothing, unless of course this in an `EditorTemplate` and/or your rendering a collection, it which case you have made things even worse by generating invalid html. Use a class name instead to access the control

Comment: @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.NumberTypeId, ....) didn't generate id=NumberTypeId" in the html since it is being dynamically generated... my solution works for me and also i have an EditorTemplate for a reason...using class name to access the control doesn't work for me since I have the same template rendering more than once and i have the ids/names being unique and using them solved my problem.